# Continued below div

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to a continued below div.

What I mean is like they have in [w3schools.com][1]

If you go to one of their turorials you will see menu in the left side, now even there is no content inside the div it still continue down (his background I mean)

I upload image that explain what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLiUD.png

I hope that you understand me, sorry on my english.

**EDIT:**
You ask for a code, but I dont try anything because I dont know what to do.
Any way, this is the page: `link removed`
Like you say to me I set the div height to 100%, dosent help.

Comment: That's just a background color rit?

Comment: `height:100%;`? Or `bottom:0;`? Include your code so we can have a look.

Comment: It has position:fixed as a background element, and then top:0; bottom:0;

Comment: Where is your code? Please read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: set height on block elements ??? use padding-bottom ;)

Comment: @099 , I dont give a code because I dont try anything, because I dont know where to start with this, anyway I edit and give link to page, Albzi, didnt help , look at my edit.

Comment: @Nati323 if you don't know where to start, and are not willing to show examples, then how can we help?

Comment: @099 What do you mean? , How can I give examples if I dont know what to do, I gave examples of what I mean, But I can't give a code because I dont know what need to be done for my request

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce** it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like that whole container is one div. Inside that div are several others that have their own height element. For example if you have a container div (using fixed just for ease right now and since you posted no code)

```
.myContainer{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
 background: #ccc;
 }
```

Inside that div you'll place the inside elements like

```
.insideMyContainer{
 float:left;
 min-height:125px; //whatever height you want or just let it be auto based on content

 }
```

Comment: But if I set to the div a fixed position its will be at the top of the page :\, Look my edit please I gave there link to page

Answer (score 0):

```
element {

padding-bottom: px; /*gives extra space*/

}
```

Don't know what you need..

**Edit:**

### step 1 - give a class name to content div

```
<div style="width:79%;display: inline-block;padding-left: 10px;" class="bigboy">
```

### step 2 - put this code insideyour  tag

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".apl").height($(".bigboy").outerHeight()+ "px");
}
</script>
```

and done :-)

[image]

Comment: But I dont know how much space will be needed, its supposue to continue until the the right content will end

Comment: @Nati323 i'm happy i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give fixed `height:1000px;` via css, or `padding-bottom:200px;` to that div...

Comment: But I dont know how much space will be needed, its supposue to continue until the the right content will end

Comment: If you want the height of one element to be the same as some other element (sibling element), you have to use javascript to calculate both heights, and then assign the "shortest" element the other element's height.